# Is there a better way of writing the below function, for faster response?

Tags: php, sql

I'm using mySQL as my main database and from there I am querying the following code:

```
 <?php

if (isset($_GET['ID'])) {

     $config = parse_ini_file("cfg.ini");
     $con = mysqli_connect($config['host'],$config['user'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']) or die ("Bad Connect: ".mysqli_connect_error());

    $ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['ID']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rec_table WHERE rec_ID='$ID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    }else {
    header('Location: 2-page.php');
}

    ?>

    <?php

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
//    echo("<title>Search - $row[item_name]</title>");

    foreach ($result as $r) {

    echo("<table>");
    echo("<tbody>");
        echo("<ul>");
        echo("<li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[icon_name].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  1 x $r[rec_Name]</li>");
        echo("<li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[ID1_icon].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  $r[QTY1] x $r[ITEM1]</li>");
  if(empty($r['ITEM2'])) {
    //show nothing
} else {      
        echo("<li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[ID2_icon].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  $r[QTY2] x $r[ITEM2]</li>");
}
  if(empty($r['ITEM3'])) {
    //show nothing
} else {
        echo("<li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[ID3_icon].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  $r[QTY3] x $r[ITEM3]</li>");
}
  if(empty($r['ITEM4'])) {
    //show nothing
} else {
        echo("<li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[ID4_icon].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  $r[QTY4] x $r[ITEM4]</li>");
}
  if(empty($r['ITEM5'])) {
    //show nothing
} else {
        echo("<li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[ID5_icon].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  $r[QTY5] x $r[ITEM5]</li>");
}
  if(empty($r['ITEM6'])) {
    //show nothing
} else {
        echo("<li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[ID6_icon].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  $r[QTY6] x $r[ITEM6]</li>");
}
  if(empty($r['ITEM7'])) {
    //show nothing
} else {
        echo("<li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[ID7_icon].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  $r[QTY7] x $r[ITEM7]</li>");
}
  if(empty($r['ITEM8'])) {
    //show nothing
} else {
        echo("<li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[ID9_icon].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  $r[QTY8] x $r[ITEM8]</li>");
}
  if(empty($r['ITEM9'])) {
    //show nothing
} else {
        echo("<li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[ID10_icon].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  $r[QTY9] x $r[ITEM9]</li>");
}
  if(empty($r['ITEM9'])) {
    //show nothing
} else {
        echo("<li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[ID10_icon].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  $r[QTY10] x $r[ITEM10]</li>");
}
        echo("</ul>");
    }
    echo("</tbody>");
echo("</table>");
    }  

    ?>
```

My code creates a list, in which it will populate the icons and name of the searched ID.
Question is if theres a different, better way of checking if the ITEMX is empty, and not show the icon or empty string in the list?

Thanks!

Comment: `if( !empty($r['ITEMX']) ){}` would be a small improvement

Comment: For less code you can use for loop `for($i=2; $i<=10; $i++){
    if( !empty($r['ITEM'.$i]) ) { echo '...'; }
}`

Comment: your HTML is invalid by the way. You cannot legitimately have a `ul` as a direct ancestor of `tbody` - it should be within a `td` which itself should be within a `tr`

Comment: A tip. Always use `exit` or `die` in case redirecting using php `header` function.

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: You should normalize your tables and not have a repeating icon field.  Although it will have an impact on performance, it will be more flexible and extendable.

Comment: I see, i will try to fix the isssues you guys pointed out. Regarding the sql injection; i am well aware. This is just in test phase, running locally, which will be fixed. @RamRaider I will test out the code you provided later, and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Totally untested but you might try something like this. A simple function that takes two arguments and returns the formatted HTML string could be called in a loop.

```
<?php


    if( empty( $_GET['ID'] ) )exit( header('Location: 2-page.php') );
    else{

        function displayicon( $r=array(), $i=false ){
            if( !empty( $r ) && array_key_exists( sprintf('ITEM%d', $i), $r ) && array_key_exists( sprintf('QTY%d', $i), $r ) ){
                return sprintf(
                    '<li><img src="/SearchEngine/Test/%s.png" align="center" alt="" class="border" />%s x %s</li>',
                    $r[ sprintf('ID%d_icon',$i) ],
                    $r[ sprintf('QTY%d',$i) ],
                    $r[ sprintf('ITEM%d',$i) ]
                );
            }
            return false;
        }




        $id=filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'ID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

        $obj = (object)parse_ini_file('cfg.ini');
        $con = new mysqli( $obj->host, $obj->user, $obj->password, $obj->dbname );


        $sql="select * from rec_table where rec_id=?";
        $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( 's', $id );
        $stmt->execute();
        $result=$stmt->get_result();



        if( $result ){
            echo "
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ul>
                                <li><img src='/SearchEngine/Test/$r[icon_name].png' align='center' class='border'>&nbsp &nbsp  1 x {[$r['rec_Name']}</li>"; 



            while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                foreach( $row as $r ){
                    for( $i=1; $i <= 9; $i++ ){
                        $li=displayicon( $i );
                        if( !empty( $li ) )echo $li;
                    }
                }
            }


            echo "
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>";          
        }
    }
?>
```